# Is it possible to assign fields to entries by category?

Tags: categories, field

I want to show some fields depending in the category selected for the entry but within the editing stage. is it possible?

If not, then how can i check if the entry is in a category in the template and output a field group.

thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the entry types to achieve the same thing?
https://buildwithcraft.com/features/entry-types

Comment: Yes, but why are Categories for then?

Comment: Categories would be used to simply classify your content within the system.  Unfortunately I don't know a way of having conditional logic in the CMS where you choose one value to display an appropriate field.